# Назначить права доступа к папке на сервере

Tags: django, nginx

У меня есть проект, размещенный в интернете (Django + Nginx + Gunicorn + Supervisor). Он работает нормально, но есть проблема с правами доступа к одной папке.

В проекте есть папка **media**. Изначально она пуста. Если залогиниться через админку на сайте и добавить пост, то в этой папке **media** должна создаться папка **post** с добавленным в пост изображением. Но у меня появляется ошибка *Permission denied 13*.

Если же создать через консоль эту папку **post** и попробовать снова добавить пост через админку, то изображение сохранится и ошибки с доступом не будет. Но при удалении поста изображение из этой папки не удаляется (хотя на локальной машине всё работает).

Я поменял права доступа на папку `chmod 777 -R media` и все заработало. Но насколько теперь знаю, такие права недопустимо ставить. На других сайтах предлагают ставить *775*, но это не работает.

Подскажите, что можно с этим сделать, чтобы при создании поста была возможность в папке **media** создать папку и сохранить в нее изображение, а при удалении поста удалить изображение из папки?

Comment: владельцем каталога должен быть пользователь, от имени которого осуществляется запись/удаление файлов в этом каталоге.

Comment: а за совет, в котором встречаются слова "chmod 777", как за любой вредный совет, следует применять меры физического воздействия.

Comment: root-пользователя отключил и создал другого пользователя. На него указывали права на папку - была та же ошибка. Затем добавил группу, где этот пользователь находится, но без результатов. Что может быть не так?

Comment: повторяю: «владельцем каталога должен быть пользователь, **от имени которого** осуществляется запись/удаление файлов в этом каталоге». добавляю: и каталога и всего его содержимого.

Comment: Подскажите, как можно узнать от какого пользователя осуществляется запись и удаление файлов?

Comment: только вы знаете, какой именно процесс пытается записывать файлы. как и любой другой процесс, он выполняется от имени какого-то пользователя. вот этот пользователь и есть тот, кому должен принадлежать каталог.

Comment: Это тот же пользователь, от которого запущен Nginx?

Comment: Сейчас попробую поменять, отпишусь чуть позже

Comment: уточнение: вполне возможно, что **и** программа nginx у вас выполняется от имени **того же** пользователя, от имени которого выполняется тот процесс, который сообщает вам об ошибке: «Permission denied 13»

Comment: Сейчас поменял значение папки на 775 и получилось удалить файл только из под root в папке media/post

Comment: Получается, что из-под root выполняется. Nginx тоже из-под root запущен

Comment: получается, что тот процесс, который пытается писать, выполняется всё-таки не от имени пользователя root. иначе этот процесс не выдавал бы вам сообщение о недостатке прав. разбирайтесь, что за процессы (и, главное, от имени каких пользователей) выполняются этой вашей смесью: «Django + Nginx + Gunicorn + Supervisor»

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Буду разбираться

Comment: Разобрался в чем проблема была. В конфигах файла с Supervisor (`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/<имя_файла>.conf`) параметр `user` был указан, как `nobody`. Заменил это значение на `root` и присвоил `root:root` к папке. Все заработало. Подскажите, так лучше оставить или поменять на другого пользователя?

Comment: вообще, с точки зрения абстрактной безопасности, процессы, обрабатывающие информацию, которая может содержать что-либо потенциально вредоносное (например, всевозможные сервисы, принимающие сетевые соединения), должны выполняться от имени самых непривилегированных пользователей.

Comment: А что касается директории /var/www/html? Там указано root:root